# Import Python file in databricks notebook

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-databricks

I am trying to import python files from databricks notebook. I am able to import the function but it keep giving me error - ***NameError: name 'col' is not defined***.

I have a file /Workspace/Shared/Common/common.py. The code in that file is:

```
def cast_datatypes(df_target, df_source):
    cols = df_target.columns
    types = [f.dataType for f in df_target.schema.fields]
    for i, c in enumerate(cols):
        df_source = df_source.withColumn(c, col(c).cast(types[i]))
    df_source = df_source.select(cols)
    return df_source
```

I am calling this function from a notebook, and did below approaches

Approach 1:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Workspace/Shared/Common/common.py")
from common import cast_datatypes
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

<Spark Session declaration>

df_final = cast_datatypes(df_target_A, df_source_A)
```

Approach 2:

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("/Workspace/Shared/Common/common.py")
import common as C
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df_final = C.cast_datatypes(df_target_A, df_source_A)
```

Both of the approach was able to import the function, but failed to use 'col'.
The error I am getting is:

```
File /Workspace/Shared/Common/common.py:13, in cast_datatypes(df_target, df_source)
     11 types = [f.dataType for f in df_target.schema.fields]
     12 for i, c in enumerate(cols):
---> 13     df_source = df_source.withColumn(c, col(c).cast(types[i]))
     14 df_source = df_source.select(cols)
     15 return df_source

NameError: name 'col' is not defined
```

Do we need to pass all the arguments that import function is using? If yes, then how did I modularize my notebooks in databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Reyk said is right.
You need to import `col` inside `common.py`.
But still you got error, even i got the same error.
After altering the `common.py` you need to `restart` the cluster or do `Detach and Re-attach` the notebook.

**/Workspace/Shared/Common/common.py**

```
def cal(df):
    re = df.withColumn("tmp", col("trip_distance") + lit(1))
    return re
```

When i tried below code i got error.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Workspace/Shared/Common/")
df = spark.sql("select * from samples.nyctaxi.trips")

from common import cal
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
display(cal(df))
```

[image]

So i added altered `common.py` like below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit

def cal(df):
    re = df.withColumn("tmp", col("trip_distance") + lit(1))
    return re
```

Again tried to call the function go same error.

[image]

But if i see contents of the file it is updated.

[image]

So, do any one of the below and re-run your code.

[image]

Output:

`tmp` column is created.

[image]

If you again do any update on that you need to re-attach notebook or restart.

If you don't want to restart or re-attach you need to reload the module `common`.

After altering the code in `common.py` just use below code.

```
import sys
import importlib
sys.path.append("/Workspace/Shared/Common/")
df = spark.sql("select * from samples.nyctaxi.trips")
if "common" in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules["common"]

from common import cal
display(cal(df))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any other ways to refresh the content the file, since we have streaming data and we do not want to stop or impact the other process because of this

Comment: You can use `importlib.reload(modulename) `. But here you need to give module name, I tried with it didn't worked so i came up with removing and again importing module with `sys.modules`.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you did not import col in the `common.py` file.

Try something like:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def cast_datatypes(df_target, df_source):
    cols = df_target.columns
    types = [f.dataType for f in df_target.schema.fields]
    for i, c in enumerate(cols):
        df_source = df_source.withColumn(c, col(c).cast(types[i]))
    df_source = df_source.select(cols)
    return df_source
```

If you want to use the same col object in your common.py function you have to pass it as an argument.

Comment: I tried this approach also, but same error :(

Comment: I think the import function is not even considering the import from common.py file